# how to convert date and time to just date in Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, array-formulas

I use Google Forms to import data from a signup form to Google Sheets, and it gives time and date stamp, I just want it to give a date and not the time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This formula works perfect

=MONTH(A2) & "/" & DAY(A2) & "/" & YEAR(A2)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SPLIT(B2:B, " "),,1)
```

or even like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(B2:B)))
```